# Javascript merge sort - words in alphabetical order

Tags: javascript, mergesort

My javascript code is:

```
$("#yes").click(function() { mergeSort(arr); });



function mergeSort(arr)
{
var arr = getDataFromInput();
    if (arr.length < 2)
        return arr;

    var middle = parseInt(arr.length / 2);
    var left   = arr.slice(0, middle);
    var right  = arr.slice(middle, arr.length);

    return merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right));
}

function merge(left, right)
{
    var result = [];

    while (left.length && right.length) {
        if (left[0] <= right[0]) {
            result.push(left.shift());
        } else {
            result.push(right.shift());
        }
    }

    while (left.length)
        result.push(left.shift());

    while (right.length)
        result.push(right.shift());
    writeResultToOutput(result);
}
function getDataFromInput() {
    return $("#w").val();
}

function writeResultToOutput(resultHTML) {
    $("#z").html(resultHTML);
}
```

My html is:

```
<body>

    <label for="w">entry information</label><br>
    <textarea rows="40" cols="100" name="w" id="w"></textarea>



    Results
    <div id="z"></div>



    <button id="yes">Begin!</button>

</body>
```

Theoretically aim is to sort this in alphabetical order using mergesort however when i type some words like 'air field bored' and press begin nothing really happens. What is wrong with that code?
Error i have received:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I am aware html is not properly linked to JavaScript but this is not a problem as obviously i know how to connect those two.

I will give you the full code after modifications is (error is gone but still does not sort words):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#yes").click(function() { mergeSort(arr); });



function mergeSort(arr)
{
var arr = getDataFromInput();
    if (arr.length < 2)
        return arr;

    var middle = parseInt(arr.length / 2);
    var left   = arr.slice(0, middle);
    var right  = arr.slice(middle, arr.length);

    return merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right));
}

function merge(left, right)
{
    var result = [];

    while (left.length && right.length) {
        if (left[0] <= right[0]) {
            result.push(left.shift());
        } else {
            result.push(right.shift());
        }
    }

    while (left.length)
        result.push(left.shift());

    while (right.length)
        result.push(right.shift());
    writeResultToOutput(result);
}
function getDataFromInput() {
    return $("#w").val();
}

function writeResultToOutput(resultHTML) {
    $("#z").html(resultHTML);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <label for="w">entry information</label><br>
    <textarea rows="40" cols="100" name="w" id="w"></textarea>



    Results
    <div id="z"></div>



    <button id="yes">Begin!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

What i want to use as arr is the input from the browser's level, I  mean:
[image]

Latest version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>


</head>
<body>

    <label for="w">entry information</label><br>
    <textarea rows="40" cols="100" name="w" id="w"></textarea>



    Results
    <div id="z"></div>



    <button id="yes">Begin!</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#yes").click(function() {
      var arr = getDataFromInput();
      mergeSort(arr); 
});


function mergeSort(arr)
{

    if (arr.length < 2)
        return arr;

    var middle = parseInt(arr.length / 2);
    var left   = arr.slice(0, middle);
    var right  = arr.slice(middle, arr.length);

    return merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right));
}

function merge(left, right)
{
    var result = [];

    while (left.length && right.length) {
        if (left[0] <= right[0]) {
            result.push(left.shift());
        } else {
            result.push(right.shift());
        }
    }

    while (left.length)
        result.push(left.shift());

    while (right.length)
        result.push(right.shift());
    writeResultToOutput(result);
}
function getDataFromInput() {
    return $("#w").val();
}

function writeResultToOutput(resultHTML) {
    $("#z").html(resultHTML);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Still no valid output, i mean no output whatsoever

Comment: Have you tried pressing F12?

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined - that is what i have in a console but i have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: Put the script wich loads in jquery before the code.

Comment: Please put the error your encountered in your question, not a comment.

Comment: How is the array passed from the form to the function?

Comment: This function i think should pass it from the form to the function:  function getDataFromInput() {
    return $("#w").val();
}

Answer (score 1):

For starters:

Your script is before your html. It starts running before it's rendered.
If you are going to leave it inside the HTML, put it before the body closing tag.

For executing a function on click, you can do it like this:

```
$("#yes").click(mergeSort());
```

No need to execute a anonymous function. You already have a named one.
And you are trying to pass a parameter that you haven't created before.
the "var arr" is inside a function.
Start checking these things and go from there. I'll be back here later.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I have moved script environment just before the body closing tag, i have changed the function click, but when it comes to "var arr" when i move it above the function that i have the error that arr is undefined...

Comment: I am sorry. It's:  $("#yes").click(mergeSort);

No "()" after the name of your function. But watch out for your loops. They may be infinite.

And... you can let the "var arr" inside the function, if it's there that you want to create it. Just don't use it out of the function, because it's not the same scope. You don't need to create it before if you will wait till the click to give it a value.

Answer (score 0):

`ReferenceError: $ is not defined` means jQuery is not included or the code is written before including jQuery in your page

Include `jQuery` library and try again
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

EDIT

You need to call our function like this

```
$("#yes").click(function() {
      var arr = getDataFromInput();
      mergeSort(arr); 
});
```

and remove  `var arr = getDataFromInput();` from mergeSort function

```
function mergeSort(arr)
{
//var arr = getDataFromInput(); this line is removed
if (arr.length < 2)
        return arr;
```

Comment: I have added the library and still not working properly.

Comment: change `$("#yes").click(function() { mergeSort(arr); });` to  `$("#yes").click(function() { mergeSort(); });`

Comment: Check my edits. You are recursively reading the textarea's value

Comment: Have done them, uploaded the latest version, still without proper output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108930/discussion-between-rohit-agre-and-mkropkowski).